# Create QML components dinamically inside repeater

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ListModel which elements have information about a data type. I'm using this in a Repeater to show a label and a component according to the datatype, but I don't know how to change that TextField (in the case of "TEXT" datatype) with a; e.g. a button to call a file dialog  in the case of "IMAGE"; or a TextField with a mask for double in the case I get datatype "REAL". How can I make this?

Here is my code:

```
Repeater {
    id: r2
    model: ListModel {
      ListElement {
        nombreCampo: "Name"
        datoValor: "John Doe"
        tipoDato: "TEXT"
      }

      ListElement {
        nombreCampo: "Birth Date"
        datoValor: "19910101"
        tipoDato: "DATE"
      }

      ListElement {
        nombreCampo: "Photo"
        datoValor: "whatever.jpg"
        tipoDato: "IMAGE"
      }

      ListElement {
        nombreCampo: "Height"
        datoValor: "1.55"
        tipoDato: "REAL"
      }
    } 

    Text {
      text: nombreCampo
    }

    // this would go well with "TEXT" but not with "DATE" (where I'd prefer a datepicker) 
    // or with "IMAGE" (where I'd prefer a button to call a file dialog).
    // so this is the part where I need to generate it according to the case
    TextField {
        text: datoValor
        placeholderText: nombreCampo
        onTextChanged: {
            r2.model.get( index ).datoValor = this.text;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt 5.12 you can use [DelegateChooser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html) + [DelegateChoice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechoice.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            id: r2
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement {
                    nombreCampo: "Name"
                    datoValor: "John Doe"
                    tipoDato: "TEXT"
                }

                ListElement {
                    nombreCampo: "Birth Date"
                    datoValor: "19910101"
                    tipoDato: "DATE"
                }

                ListElement {
                    nombreCampo: "Photo"
                    datoValor: "whatever.jpg"
                    tipoDato: "IMAGE"
                }

                ListElement {
                    nombreCampo: "Height"
                    datoValor: "1.55"
                    tipoDato: "REAL"
                }
            }

            delegate: DelegateChooser {
                role: "tipoDato"
                DelegateChoice {
                    roleValue: "DATE"
    //                delegate: SomeDatePicker {
    //                    date: datoValor
    //                }
                }
                DelegateChoice {
                    roleValue: "IMAGE"
                    delegate: Button {
                        text: "Select image"
                    }
                }
                DelegateChoice {
                    roleValue: "TEXT"
                    delegate: TextField {
                        text: model.datoValor
                    }
                }
                DelegateChoice {
                    roleValue: "REAL"
                    delegate: TextField {
                        text: model.datoValor
                        // inputMask: ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In earlier versions, you can use [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html), and choose the source/sourceComponent based on the model data.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a loader inside your delegate.

```
Column{
    Repeater{
        model: // your model
        delegate: Loader{
            anchors{
                right: parent.right
                left: parent.left
            }
            sourceComponent: {
                if(tipoDato=== "TEXT")      {return textFieldComponent;}
                else if(tipoDato=== "DATE") {return datePickerComponent;}
                else if(tipoDato=== "IMAGE"){return imagePickerPickerComponent;}
                else if(tipoDato=== "REAL") {return floatPickerComponent;}
            }
        }
    }
}

// Component definition

Component{
    id: textFieldComponent
    // Define your component here
}
Component{
    id: datePickerComponent
    // Define your component here
}
Component{
    id: imagePickerPickerComponent
    // Define your component here
}
Component{
    id: floatPickerComponent
    // Define your component here
}
```

If you use this example take into account that each component has to have their height defined and the top parent column has to have their width defined in order to render all the items correctly.